# findBy foreign key in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `EncodingResult` that references three others. I want to find out how to use the repository's `findBy()` methods to return an entity based on its `foreignKey` so that I can, for example, make a `GET` request passing a Video's foreign key as a parameter and return whether or not there is an `EncodingResult` containing a Video with the given `foreignKey`.

How would you go about doing this? I tried reading a bit on `EntityGraphs` and was rather confused. There also doesn't seem to be a great number of content explaining these parts of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you posted the code for your entities, but from your description, I think you have something like this:

```
@Entity
public class EncodingResult {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "encodingResult")
  private List<Video> videos=new ArrayList<Video>();

  //...boilerplate
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Video {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  EncodingResult encodingResult;

  //...boilerplate
}
```

So you can define findBy methods in your `EncodingResultRepository` like so.

```
public interface EncodingResultRepository extends JpaRespository<EncodingResult, Integer> {

  public Optional<EncodingResult> findByVideoName(String name);

  public Optional<EncodingResult> findByVideoId(Integer id);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression I'd have to find out whether Video existed or not first and then passing the entity to the repo! Many thanks, I assume this works for multiple entity queries, using `And`, right?

Comment: Yes. It has a lot of features. You can see more here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details